# python setup.py directory permissions

Tags: python, packaging, setup.py

I am trying to create a setup.py that will build rpm/deb packages and I want it to create a blank directory with 777 permissions. I have it creating the directory via data_files

```
  data_files=[ 
                ( '/var/spool/my_dir', [] )
             }
```

But it creates the directory with 755 permissions. How do i get setup.py to create this directory with 777 permissions??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [set file permission in setup.py file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5932804/set-file-permission-in-setup-py-file)

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to do this. You will need to override the `install` method. See my answer here:
[set file permissions in setup.py file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5932804/set-file-permission-in-setup-py-file/25761434#25761434)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way to specify file permissions in the call to `setup`.

You could always `import os` and do something like `os.chmod('/var/spool/my_dir', 0777)` after the `setup` call.  To be honest though, I wonder if you *really* need those permissions.

Comment: thanks for the reply John. I don't think os.chmod works when building an rpm/deb package (i could be wrong). Thanks again.