# Set permissions on data_files in setup.py

Tags: python, setuptools, distutils

I have a setup.py and I use fpm on that setup.py to create my python packages (debs and rpms). It works really well for upstart and systemd distros, but for systemv (debian7 specifically) I run into an issue with file permissions.

I need the /etc/init.d/ltsense script to be executable. Is this something I can do with data_files in the setup.py, or is this something I need to do with a post-install script passed to fpm?

Here is part of my setup.py:

```
...

from setuptools import setup, find_packages
import os
import platform
import math


def init_system():
    """
    Returns a tuple of init data files and a version suffix (deb only).
    Example: (('/etc/init/', ['scripts/upstart/ltsense.conf']),'~upstart')
    """
    distro = os.getenv('DISTRO', platform.linux_distribution()[0])
    release = os.getenv('RELEASE', platform.linux_distribution()[1])
    if distro == 'Ubuntu':
        return (('/etc/init/', ['scripts/upstart/ltsense.conf']),
                '~upstart')
    elif distro in ['debian']:
        release_int = int(math.floor(float(release)))
        if release_int == 7:
            return (('/etc/init.d/', ['scripts/systemv/ltsense']),
                   '~systemv')
        elif release_int == 8:
            return (('/lib/systemd/system/', ['scripts/systemd/ltsense.service']),
                   '~systemd')
    elif distro in ['centos', 'redhat', 'fedora']:
        return (('/lib/systemd/system/', ['scripts/systemd/ltsense.service']),'')

setup(
    name='ltsense',
    version='{}{}'.format(os.popen('git describe --dirty').readlines()[0].strip(),init_system()[1]),
    packages=find_packages(),
    author='Sumit Khanna',
    author_email='sumit@penguindreams.org',
    maintainer='Sumit Khanna',
    maintainer_email='sumit@penguindreams.org',
    url='http://bigsense.io',
    license='GNU General Public License v3',
    description='ltsense sensor collection and relay service',
    long_description=open('README').read(),
    data_files=[init_system()[0],
                ('/etc/ltsense/examples', ['etc/virtual-ltsense.conf',
                                           'etc/onewire-ltsense.conf'])
                ],
    entry_points={'console_scripts': ['ltsense=ltsense.__main__:main']},

...
```

**EDIT: Not a Duplicate:** This was marked a [possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5932804). My question deals with making packages via fpm, not setting permissions directly with the python setup script. I feel my solution is much cleaner than the linked duplicate for my particular use case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [set file permission in setup.py file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5932804/set-file-permission-in-setup-py-file)

Answer (score 0):

I decided to do this in a `post-install` script instead which I pass to `fpm` using `--after-install`. It works for both the rpms and debs:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ -f /etc/init.d/ltsense ]; then
  chmod 755 /etc/init.d/ltsense
fi
```