# How to minimize JSON data before publishing on PyPi?

Tags: python, json, pypi

We have big project which works with `*.json` files in the directory: `project/data/{locale}/*.json`.

And we need to minify the contents of json files. We already created [script which minify](https://gist.github.com/lk-geimfari/82571db0b1b548c7830dc4cb6e394b099) all json files in directory, but what we actually need is minimizing json files only in package which will publish, i.e `dist/package.v0.1.1.tar.gz`.

Does `distutils` provides some API for doing this? Can we minify json data only in production version of our library, which will hosted on PyPi.org?

Maybe something like this:

```
# setup.py
from distutils import before_publish

@before_publish
def minify_json():
   # logic here
```

Comment: Been a long time, but I think you can override `install` using the `cmdclass` property.

Comment: I will try this. Thanks.

Comment: I guess the trick is to find the correct command to override. I'm not sure if there is any specific command that runs for `bdist_wheel` only that could minifly all json files in the `build` folder so the `.whl` file will contain the compressed files. Docs can be very confusing.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25761434/1754709 could be a starting point

Comment: As far as I can tell it's looks suitable for me. Thank you!