# Change permissions of installed files with setuptools

Tags: python-3.x, file-permissions, setuptools

I am currently developing a python package that can be installed with `setup.py` using `setuptools`. The package uses `svn` as source control and I am developing on windows. For some files, `svn` automatically sets the file permissions to write-protected (because of the `svn` lock mechanism). For example, the package contains a .png file that will be installed with the package and `svn` always sets the .png file permission to write-protected.

Unfortunately, `python -m pip install` shows an error when removing the temporary build directory, since it cannot remove the write-protected files (*access denied: 'example.png'*). I can manually remove the write-protection from the source file and then install the package, which succeeds. However, `svn` automatically resets the permissions after updating the repository.

Is it possible to configure my `setup.py` script so that it copies only the file content and uses some default permissions on the target?

My `setup.py` looks like this. The relevant part that copies the files is the `package_data`.

```
import setuptools

setuptools.setup(
    name="my_package",
    version="1.0.0",
    author="Me",
    author_email="example@example.com",
    description="Awesome package",
    classifiers=[
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
        "Operating System :: OS Independent"
    ],
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    package_data={
        "my_package": ["ui/*.png", "ui/*.ui"]
    },
    python_requires=">=3.5",
    install_requires=["pyqt5==5.9"]
)
```

Edit: Changing the file permissions after copying the files resolved the issue. As hoefling's comment suggests, this answer shows how to do this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25761434/6095394

Comment: Check whether [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25761434/2650249) will help.

Comment: Yes, changing the permissions after copying the files (as described in your link) seems to work. I think the permission error occurred in a cleanup step when `setuptools` removed the files from the temporary build directory. Should I mark this question as a duplicate?

Comment: It's up to you. If you could use the answer without any crucial modifications to its code, then it makes sense to mark duplicate as it solves your issue. If not, you may also write an answer to your own question; either way, both questions are linked now.